# sequelize db:seed:all . not working

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

So I'm writing a small project for a coding bootcamp and it's my job in the group to get migrations to work.  From the terminal if i do sequelize db:migrate it creates all the tables from my migrations folder but i have all of my dummy data in 5 seperate seed.sql files in a db folder, and I cannot get them to run.

Brads-MBP:group-project-2 b-rad$ sequelize db:seed:all
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
No seeders found.

Thats what happens when I try and run the command.  Any ideas?

Comment: Seed in Sequelize looks like migration but located in seeder directory.
You can create new seed by command: ```sequelize seed:create --name=my-seed```. When you run ```sequelize db:seed:all``` all seeds applys

Comment: yea you are putting them in a non standard location. they should be in a seeders directory to run that command.

Answer (score 2):

You are putting them in a non-standard location. 
The standard location is a `seeders` directory which should be on the same level as your migrations directory and models directory

if you want to keep them in that folder you have to do

`Sequelize db:seed:all --seed /path/to/location`

Edit:

The following will run one specific seed.

`Sequelize db:seed:all --seed /path/to/seed-location.json`

To run all the seed files in a directory

`Sequelize db:seed:all --seeders-path /path/to/seeds/directory`

Comment: `--seed` should be `--seeders-path`